# Thread PrintService "extra_select_printer" usage

Tags: android

I have a added a "Select Printer" button on the printer info screen and would like it to select that printer and go the preview page once its clicked. Trying to use "EXTRA_SELECT_PRINTER" and "EXTRA_CAN_SELECT_PRINTER" constants to implement this. I tried using those as mentioned in the document but after setting the result in the activity with extra_select_printer as true it goes to the main landing page instead of going to the print preview page. I would appreciate if anyone can help us with this.

Thanks!